# convert unix_timestamp to timestamp in oracle

Tags: oracle

How to convert unix_timestamp to timestamp in oracle?

I used the below function but it didn't work.
"UNIX_TIMESTAMP(event_time_stamp)"

This is the complete query :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h1YY.jpg)

Comment: Did you do any research before posting this?

Comment: yes we tried but we didn't get solution.

Comment: Unix timestamp = 1511421211 need to convert this to oracle timestamp = '2017-12-11 11:50:54'

Comment: I think we should get November 23 from this, q.v. my answer below.

Comment: The actual error you get is `ORA-00904: Invalid identifier`. This is because `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is not a function defined in your system. It is certainly not an Oracle built-in; of course not, Oracle is OS-agnostic (what would such a function return when the database is running on Windows ?)

Answer (score 1):

The UNIX timestamp represents the number of seconds which have elapsed since January 1, 1970.  Oracle allows adding some number of days directly to a timestamp.  We can build the timestamp you want by adding the appropriate number of days in your UNIX timestamp value to `1970-01-01 00:00:00`:

```
SELECT
    TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(1511421211, 'second')
FROM dual;
```

This returns the following:

```
23.11.2017 07:13:31
```

### Demo

Comment: Hi, i tried to execute the below query but it's throwing me error : SELECT
    TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' +     
    numtodsinterval(1511421211, 'second'),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM dual

Comment: Error : ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: @sandoep This is a different question.  You should ask a new question in this case.

Comment: @sandoep: the `to_date()` in your query is useless, you don't need it

Comment: `CAST( TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + numtodsinterval(1511421211, 'second') AS DATE )` or just `DATE '1970-01-01' + numtodsinterval(1511421211, 'second')`