# TO_DATE ISSUE IN CONVERSION

Tags: oracle

I tried to execute the below query but it's throwing me `error` :

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
        TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + numtodsinterval(1511421211, 'second')
        ,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
FROM dual
```

**Error :** `ORA-01830:` date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: Clearly you are trying to run the code from [this recent answer on unix timestamps in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47766750/146325) but some reason you are not running the actual code. There is no need to use `to_date()` to cast a TIMESTAMP to a DATE: Oracle just handles that for us.

Comment: @APC And for some reason it is a new screen name.  Strange.

Comment: @Tim we both are friends sitting aside and working :)

Answer (score 1):

The `TO_DATE( datestring, format_model )` function takes strings as arguments.

Your query:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
        TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + numtodsinterval(1511421211, 'second')
        ,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
       ) 
FROM   dual
```

Is passing a `TIMESTAMP` and a string so Oracle has to perform an implicit conversion from `TIMESTAMP` to a string so your function is effectively:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
        TO_CHAR(
          TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + numtodsinterval(1511421211, 'second'),
          (
            SELECT value
            FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
            WHERE parameter = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT'
          )
        ),
        'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
       ) 
FROM   dual
```

If the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session paramter does not match your format model `'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'` then an exception will be raised.

You could change the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` parameter - but this is a session parameter that is set per user and each user can change it at any time during their session so this should **NOT** be the solution.

Instead, you can just use a `DATE` literal instead of a `TIMESTAMP` literal:

```
SELECT DATE '1970-01-01' + NUMTODSINTERVAL (1511421211, 'second')
FROM   DUAL
```

Or, if you want to use a timestamp then you can use the `CAST` function:

```
SELECT CAST(
         TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + NUMTODSINTERVAL (1511421211, 'second')
         AS DATE
       )
FROM   DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax appear somewhat incorrect to me. Try this:

```
SELECT   TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL (1511421211, 'second')
  FROM DUAL;
```

Edit:

As @a_horse.. said "*Oracle DATE always contains a time*",so if timestamp is not visible then you just need to see your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` in table `V$NLS_PARAMETERS`. In your case its simply set to

> NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY';

So you need to `alter` the session first to get the `timestamp` in `SQLPLUS`. See below:

```
SQL> alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'mm-dd-yyyy HH24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL>   SELECT   TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + NUMTODSINTERVAL (15114212
11, 'second')  FROM DUAL;

TO_DATE('1970-01-01
-------------------
11-23-2017 07:13:31
```

Comment: The OP is running code from another thread - see my comment on the question.

Comment: That can be further simplified to `DATE '1970-01-01' + NUMTODSINTERVAL (1511421211, 'second')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is also correct. I didnot touch the original post of OP, just rearranged it.

Comment: if you execute above query we get only date but not the time.

Comment: I need both date and time

Comment: @Prasad: an Oracle `DATE` always contains a time

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name : but on oracle 12 i am getting only date. SQL> SELECT   TO_DATE ('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  2         + NUMTODSINTERVAL (1511421211, 'second')
  3    FROM DUAL;

TO_DATE('
---------
23-NOV-17

SQL>

Comment: @XING tried the updated one worked fine but when trying to compare the below where condition "unixts_to_date(evt.event_time_stamp) > trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' day;"  in oracle But in mysql i have same  comparison and i am getting result and the condition is  "from_unixtime(evt.event_time_stamp) > date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day) "  Please help me in this conversion from mysql to oracle

Comment: @Prasad: a `DATE` always contains a time in Oracle. There is no way to get a date without it. If you don't see, configure your SQL client to display the time part of a date.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting?

```
select to_char(DATE '1970-01-01' + NUMTODSINTERVAL (1511421211, 'second'), 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual;
```

Comment: This is the query i am running and expecting the out put as --                                        select 
     UNIX_TIMESTAMP(evt.event_time_stamp) as "---- Time -------------",
from
    ap.ALTEREVT evt
where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(evt.event_time_stamp) > trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' day;

Expected output : 

2017-12-11 11:50:54  
2017-12-11 12:55:07  
2017-12-12 10:07:04  
2017-12-12 10:07:05

Comment: I believe this post can help your need.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105691/convert-timestamp-datatype-into-unix-timestamp-oracle

Comment: i tried this procedure and unable to get values as expected create or replace 
FUNCTION unix_ts_to_date( p_unix_ts IN NUMBER )
  RETURN DATE
IS
  l_date DATE;
BEGIN
  l_date := date '1970-01-01' + p_unix_ts/60/60/24;
  RETURN l_date;
END;

Comment: @arunb2w Oracle Date has always timestamp within. There is no need to cast using to_char to show timestamp.